# DeepPartial error on initAuth0 auth0 - nextjs + typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, auth0

Trying to implement auth0 on nextjs typescript.
But on initAuth0, I get below error of deep partials,

```
Argument of type '{ clientId: string; clientSecret: string; scope: string; domain: string; redirectUri: string; postLogoutRedirectUri: string; session: {}; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DeepPartial<Config>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'clientId' does not exist in type 'DeepPartial<Config>'. Did you mean to write 'clientID'?ts(2345)
```

initAuth0 code,

```
import { initAuth0 } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0";

export default initAuth0({
  clientId: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
  scope: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH0_SCOPE || "openid profile",
  domain: process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN,
  redirectUri:
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_REDIRECT_URI ||
    "http://localhost:3000/api/callback",
  postLogoutRedirectUri:
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_POST_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URI ||
    "http://localhost:3000/",
  session: {
    // cookieSecret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
    // cookieLifetime: Number(process.env.SESSION_COOKIE_LIFETIME) || 7200,
  },
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is the last part of the error,

> Did you mean to write 'clientID'?

In your config object, you have written `clientId` (note the lowercase `d`), the config object accepted by initAuth0, however, [expects `clientID`](https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0/blob/50e27fc09d2a78c69d26b0f97bc2fcbec536c746/src/auth0-session/get-config.ts#L96).

One of the most frustrating things about TypeScript is the overbearing error messages. I hope they improve them in the future.

Comment: Thanks that's correct! I was following some tutorial videos, and it seems like the structure has changed a lot. And I started following exact instructions on https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0/tree/50e27fc09d2a78c69d26b0f97bc2fcbec536c746 which worked! Cheers